# React Hooks useCallback dependency infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, usecallback

I'm currently fetching my data once when the component mounts, then whenever the user clicks a button. I want however to stop the button from fetching if a request is in progress, that's why I'm updating the `isFetching` state.

However, I need to add the `isFetching` to the `useCallback` dependency to remove the warning and if I do, an infinite fetch loop is triggered.

Here's my code:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const isMounted = useRef(true);
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);
  
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  
  // Can also be called from the button click
  const getMyData = useCallback(() => {
    if (isFetching) return;
    setIsFetching(true);
    fetch('get/my/data')
      .then((res) => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setData(res.data);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setData("Error fetching data");
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setIsFetching(false);
        }
      });
  }, []); // isFetching dependency warning as is, if added then infinite loop

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    getMyData();
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, [getMyData]);

  return (
    <div>
        <button onClick={getMyData}>Update data</button>
        <p>{data}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I understand that there are multiple questions like this one, but I couldn't remove the warning or infinite loop while still checking if the component is mounted.

Here are some examples: [example-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543368/react-hooks-useeffect-adding-dependency-triggers-infinite-loop), [example-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59960307/react-infinite-update-loop-with-usecallback-react-hooks-exhaustive-deps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert `isFetching` to a ref, so it's value won't be a dependency of the function:

```js
const { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;

const MyComponent = () => {
  const isMounted = useRef(true);
  const isFetching = useRef(false);
  
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
  // Can also be called from the button click
  const getMyData = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('call');
    if (isFetching.current) return;
    isFetching.current = true;
    fetch('https://cat-fact.herokuapp.com/facts')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setData(res);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
          setData("Error fetching data");
        }
      })
      .finally(() => {
        if (isMounted.current) {
          isFetching.current = false;
        }
      });
  }, []); // isFetching dependency warning as is, if added then infinite loop

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    getMyData();
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, [getMyData]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={getMyData}>Update data</button>
      <ul>
      {
        data.map(({ _id, text }) => (
          <li key={_id}>{text}</li>
        ))
      }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  root
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: How to use this ref to toggle loading indicator?

Comment: Changing the ref won't cause a re-render, and the view won't change. You'll need to add another state (`loading`), and toggle it while you toggle the fetching ref.